# write to csv file using separator

Tags: r

I want to write my resulted matrix into csv file.

I used the code

```
write.table(result, file ="F:\\filename.csv",row.names=FALSE,sep=",")
```

But my results already having some "," value,so what type of separator use to write these type of data.

I already used 'tab' as the separator but at that time it did not split as column, the values were inserted into a single column.

I also tried

```
  write.csv(result, file ="F:\\filename.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

but this time the single column content is splited into multiple column .

Comment: Maybe tell us how you would like your data to be written. Usually, `,` within the data should not matter in `write.table`, as by default strings are quoted by `"`.

Comment: classically in countries where `,` is used as a decimal separator (France and Germany for example), "csv" files are actually semi-colon separated (it is the default on all spreadsheet program if you install those countries specific version). So `write.table(result, file ="F:\\filename.csv",row.names=FALSE,sep=";")` would be quite classic. Otherwise for a tab-delimited files the argument is `sep="\t"`.

Comment: @plannapus Make that an answer?

Answer (score 26):

In countries where `,` is used as a decimal separator (France and Germany for example), "csv" files are actually semi-colon separated (it is the default on all spreadsheet program if you install those countries specific version).
So `write.table(result, file ="F:\\filename.csv",row.names=FALSE,sep=";")` would be quite classic.
So classic actually that there is a wrapper for it:

```
write.csv2(result, file ="F:\\filename.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

`write.csv2` use `sep=";"` and `dec=","` as default.

Otherwise for a tab-delimited files the argument is `sep="\t"`.

Comment: Instead of `sep="\t"`,  `"write_delim(object, path = "filepath/filename.txt", delim = "\t")"`, can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use **`qmethod = "double"`** and therefore the separators don't interfere with field content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what ever delimiter you want, also note that you can use a string as a delimiter. So some non-standard examples might be "||" or "|/|". This is particularly helpful if one of the fields already contains some other kinds of delimiters such as ";" "," ":", or "|".