# write function with separator

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [write to csv file using separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758957/write-to-csv-file-using-separator)

I recentely asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758957/write-to-csv-file-using-separator) on how to write a csv.

Now I have a column in the data which contains news, which has **more** than one 'comma' inside the data. When I use `write.csv()` it splits the column into different rows with some comma values. I have also tried `write.csv2()` and `write.table ()`

How do I write the csv without splitting the column?

Comment: Please post a comment to your previous question instead of opening a new one.

Comment: And read the help files ...

Comment: @Roland, i coudnt comment the above question that is why i opened a new one, sorry for that.

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question.

Comment: You will have to post an exact sample of your data.  You haven't said whether they are character strings or something else, nor what locale you are running under.   If some character is splitting a value into multiple *rows*  that is not the fault of a separator character -- more like an EndOfLine character.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at what is mentioned behind sep in the help files (`help(write.csv)`)